# ElasticSearch: filter out multiple ranges of dates

Tags: mongodb, date, search, elasticsearch, search-engine

I am trying to make a search engine like Airbnb (for cars) where when you search, you need to filter the `distance` and also check for the availability of the item (if it has been reserved on the dates I am searching for, it should not be a hit). This means that the searched date range needs to check against each future reservation date ranges.

In the MongoDB database, I am currently storing my reservation dates for the items as an array of date objects:

```
    // Future reservations:
    [{startDate: d1, endDate: d2}, {startDate: d3, endDate: d4}, ...]
```

I am not sure how to map this in ElasticSearch and how can I filter out documents whose date ranges are falling in the searched date range.

This query object is all I have got so far:

```
        {
            "filtered" : {
                "query" : {
                    "multi_match" : {
                        "query" : "white toyota",
                        "fields" : [ "title^2", "description" ]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                                "geo_distance" : {
                                    "distance" : "50km",
                                    "location" : [-122.3050, 37.9174]
                                }
                } // * Add another filter to check start and end dates not fall on future reservation dates
            }
        };
```

(Please note that I do not have much experience with ElasticSearch)

#### EDIT1:

Here is a sample data:

```
{
    title: "Toyota Camry",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, wisi option nam an. Eam ad vulputate expetendis, equidem omnesque efficiantur mei at. Us"
    pricePerDay: 90,
    location: [-126.3050, 37.9174],
    upcomingReservations: [
                                {startDate: "05/03/2015", endDate: "05/10/2015"},
                                {startDate: "05/15/2015", endDate: "05/18/2015"}
                          ]
}
```

I think I will have a separate Reservations colection in Mongo but I will denormalize the dates when transforming data into ElasticSearch (as shown above with `upcomingReservations`).

Now, If I search for a "Toyota", for dates "04/30/2015" to "05/02/2015" within the distance, I should get a hit. However, if I select a date range of "05/17/2015" - "05/21/2015", it should not be a hit because one of the future reservations fall in that range.

PS. The data format can be changed. I just thought having future reservations as array of dateRange object would be useful.

Comment: Do you only need dates? Or also times?

Comment: For this you need to use the `range` to filter the dates and please provide the sample data then only i can help you to build the es query

Comment: @JettroCoenradie I only need dates.

Comment: @Sarohan Thanks for your suggestion. I did look into `range` but I was not sure how to fit that into my problem. I have just added a sample data in the question.

Comment: The reason I asked about the dates is that it might be good enough to store all the dates that are reserved in one array using format yyyymmdd and than create a bool filter using the must_not part? Of course I do not know how many dates would be in the reserved array but I use something similar before.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Yes, I was actually considering that option too and saw this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21606608/804503 . I am open to that option. I just wanted to see if there was a better solution possible. If you could post an answer, I would accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JettroCoenradie In the method you described, is it possible to do that when we have date ranges on both the sides (data and the search query)? I mean, let's say I store my reservations in an array. But now I am still searching with a Start and End date and none of the dates in between should fall in the reserved dates. Could you give me an idea on how to go about this? Thanks