# Elasticsearch query to check date range not in date array

Tags: arrays, date, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a 'reservations' field which stores an array of dates that an item has been reserved for.

Sample data:

```
{
   reservations: [ "05/03/2015",
                   "05/04/2015",
                   "05/05/2015",
                   "05/18/2015",
                   "05/19/2015"
                  ]
}
```

I'd like to search for a date range in elastic search and return all items that do not contain dates falling on these dates.

So I have a `startDate` and `endDate` parameter to search for. However, the date range filter for elasticsearch will not fit this requirement. Can I do this in some other way?

**EDIT:**

I think the Date Range filter wont work because you can only compare the `startDate` and `endDate` with `gte` or `lt` to just ONE value on the right. I basically have a bunch of dates on the left (start/end date range) that I need to check against and bunch of dates on the right (the multiple reservation dates).

Comment: Why wouldn't the date range work? Can you give more details? Sounds like you tried something and didn't work

Comment: @AndreiStefan I actually started with a different way to handle this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820179/elasticsearch-filter-out-multiple-ranges-of-dates).

But I simplified the way I'm storing the reserved dates - in plain array. But I think the Date Range filter wont work because you can only compare the `startDate` and `endDate` with `gte` or `lt` to just ONE value on the right. I basically have a bunch of dates on the left (start/end date range) that I need to check against and bunch of dates on the right (the multiple reservation dates).

Comment: @AyrtonSenna did you find any solution?

Comment: @musa not really, nothing yet.. I'm just using a workaround by sorting the result on the front-end AFTER elasticsearch has sent back the results. (Not ideal)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using nested object. Convert reservations as a nested object to the main document and than range queries will work.

Example

```
{
  reservation : [
    {"thedate" : "2015-01-01"}, 
    {"thedate" : "2015-03-12"},
    ...
  ]
}
```